Hypothesis testing for correlation in bivariate normal sample
Assume that $(X_1, Y_1), . . . , (X_n, Y_n)$ are independent bivariate normal random
vectors with parameters $(\mu,\mu, \sigma^2, \sigma^2, \rho)$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are known. We are interested in testing the null hypothesis $H_0 : \rho = 0$ against the alternative $H_1 : \rho = 0.5$. However, we were only able to observe $(U_i,V_i)$, where $U_i = max(X_i, Y_i)$ and $V_i = min(X_i, Y_i)$ .
Based on the observed sample, obtain the test statistic corresponding to the most powerful test of $H_0$ against $H_1$. Also find a critical value so that the size of the test converges to 0.05 as $n → ∞$
My attempt:
Case 1: $X_i>Y_i$
$\implies U_i = X_i, V_i = Y_i$
Joint pdf of $(U_i,V_i)$, $f_{u,v}(u,v) = f_{x,y}(x,y)$
$\implies f_{u,v}(u,v)$ is bivariate normal with $(\mu,\mu, \sigma^2, \sigma^2, \rho)$
Case 2: $X_i<Y_i$
$\implies U_i = Y_i, V_i = X_i$
Joint pdf of $(U_i,V_i)$, $f_{u,v}(u,v) = f_{x,y}(x,y)|-1|$
$\implies f_{u,v}(u,v)$ is bivariate normal with $(\mu,\mu, \sigma^2, \sigma^2, \rho)$ as $f_{x,y}(x,y) = f_{x,y}(y,x)$
On combining cases, we get that $f_{u,v}(u,v)$ is bivariate normal with $(\mu,\mu, \sigma^2, \sigma^2, \rho)$
Then, $U_i-V_i\sim N(0,2\sigma^2(1-\rho))$.
There is something not right here as $U_i-V_i$ is always positive. What am I doing wrong and how to proceed here?

Obviously, since $\Pr[U_i \ge V_i] = 1$, it is impossible for the joint density $f(u,v)$ to be bivariate normal.  The support is on the set $u \ge v$ which is half of the real plane.  When you separated the two cases for $X_i$ versus $Y_i$, you did not incorporate those conditions into the transformed joint density, so you cannot write $f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

You might prefer to look at the distribution of $(U_i-V_i)^2$ which will be the same as $(X_i-Y_i)^2$

Thanks for your hint @henry as i was earlier trying to go with $(U_i-V_i)$.
Since $T_i(\rho)=\frac{(U_i-V_i)^2}{2\sigma^2(1-\rho)}\sim \chi^2(1)$, after applying NP Lemma the rejection region comes out to be $Z=\frac{\sum T_i(0)}{n}<k$. B,y central limit theorem, $\frac{Z-1}{\sqrt\frac{2}{n}}$ converges in dist to $N(0,1)$. $P_{H_o}(\frac{Z-1}{\sqrt\frac{2}{n}}<$$\frac{k-1}{\sqrt\frac{2}{n}})=0.05$ implies that, for large n, the critical value is, $k=1+\sqrt\frac{2}{n}z_{0.05}$ or would it be $k=1$.
